# spring mvc swaggger ui getting xml response but the swagger ui requires json format

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

Day before yesterday I came to know about swagger.Its fantastic.But may be because of my lack of knowledge there is something I am unable to do. I tried hard to solve it and finally I putting it as a question here.

my pom.xml

```
<dependency>

        <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>

        <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>

        <version>0.5.2</version>

 </dependency>
```

I have added this dependency.
my servlet-context.xml is as below.I did bind the swagger configuration bean and make this config configurations enabled.

```
<!-- Configuration Bean -->


<bean id="documentationConfig" class="com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.DocumentationConfig"/>
<context:annotation-config />

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Create the swagger.properties with the following entries.

```
documentation.services.version=1.0
documentation.services.basePath=http://localhost:8080/swagger
```

and include the same in myapplication context the way any other property files are included.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/swagger.properties" />
```

my controller to document the api and its methods

```
@Controller    

@Api(value="onlinestore", description="Operations pertaining to Online Store")

@RequestMapping(value="/onlinestore")       

public class OnlineStoreController {

@Autowired

private IStoreFront storeFrontService;           

@ApiOperation(value = "View the Specific info of the product")

@RequestMapping(value="/authorize/viewProduct/{productid}", method=RequestMethod.GET)     

public ResponseEntity<Object> viewProduct(@ApiParam(name="productId", value="The Id of the product to be viewed", required=true)
```

Now by clicking the following link I am able to see the documenation

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger/api-docs
```

the result is as below

```
<ApiDocumentation>
<apiVersion>1.0</apiVersion>
<apis>
<description>Operations pertaining to Online Store</description>
<path>/api-docs/onlinestore</path>
</apis>
<basePath>http://localhost:8080/swagger</basePath>
<swaggerVersion>1.0</swaggerVersion>
</ApiDocumentation>
```

it returns xml format. Then I integrated the swagger UI using the following link `https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui`. 
The index.html page is as below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Swagger UI</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
  <link href='css/typography.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  <link href='css/reset.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  <link href='css/screen.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  <link href='css/reset.css' media='print' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  <link href='css/print.css' media='print' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  <script src='lib/jquery-1.8.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/jquery.slideto.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/jquery.wiggle.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/handlebars-2.0.0.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/js-yaml.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/lodash.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/backbone-min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='swagger-ui.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/highlight.9.1.0.pack.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/highlight.9.1.0.pack_extended.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/jsoneditor.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/marked.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/swagger-oauth.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

  <!-- Some basic translations -->
  <!-- <script src='lang/translator.js' type='text/javascript'></script> -->
  <!-- <script src='lang/ru.js' type='text/javascript'></script> -->
  <!-- <script src='lang/en.js' type='text/javascript'></script> -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      var url = window.location.search.match(/url=([^&]+)/);
      if (url && url.length > 1) {
        url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
      } else {
        url = "http://localhost:8080/swagger/api-docs";
      }

      hljs.configure({
        highlightSizeThreshold: 5000
      });

      // Pre load translate...
      if(window.SwaggerTranslator) {
        window.SwaggerTranslator.translate();
      }
      window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
        url: url,
        dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
        supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch'],
        onComplete: function(swaggerApi, swaggerUi){
          if(typeof initOAuth == "function") {
            initOAuth({
              clientId: "your-client-id",
              clientSecret: "your-client-secret-if-required",
              realm: "your-realms",
              appName: "your-app-name",
              scopeSeparator: ",",
              additionalQueryStringParams: {}
            });
          }

          if(window.SwaggerTranslator) {
            window.SwaggerTranslator.translate();
          }
        },
        onFailure: function(data) {
          log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");
        },
        docExpansion: "none",
        jsonEditor: false,
        defaultModelRendering: 'schema',
        showRequestHeaders: false
      });

      window.swaggerUi.load();

      function log() {
        if ('console' in window) {
          console.log.apply(console, arguments);
        }
      }
  });
  </script>
</head>

<body class="swagger-section">
<div id='header'>
  <div class="swagger-ui-wrap">
    <a id="logo" href="http://swagger.io"><img class="logo__img" alt="swagger" height="30" width="30" src="images/logo_small.png" /><span class="logo__title">swagger</span></a>
    <form id='api_selector'>
      <div class='input'><input placeholder="http://example.com/api" id="input_baseUrl" name="baseUrl" type="text"/></div>
      <div id='auth_container'></div>
      <div class='input'><a id="explore" class="header__btn" href="#" data-sw-translate>Explore</a></div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="message-bar" class="swagger-ui-wrap" data-sw-translate>&nbsp;</div>
<div id="swagger-ui-container" class="swagger-ui-wrap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the when I click this link `http://localhost:8080/swagger/dist/index.html`

[image]

I am getting as above. Clearly it tells me that it is expecting json but getting xml as input as `http://localhost:8080/swagger/api-docs` is returning xml. It is axpecting something like this :

{
  "ApiDocumentation": {
    "apiVersion": "1.0",
    "apis": {
      "description": "Operations pertaining to Online Store",
      "path": "/api-docs/onlinestore"
    },
    "basePath": "http://localhost:8080/onlineStore",
    "swaggerVersion": "1.0"
  }
}

I am unable to understand where did I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first make sure that your server is configured to produce JSON:

```
curl -H Accept:application/json http://localhost:8080/swagger/api-docs
```

And if you don't get JSON back, you have a server configuration issue.  If this shows JSON, it's possible that your server is expecting a different Accept header, like `application/json;charset=UTF8`, in which case you can tell swagger-ui to send that instead of just `application/json`:

```
 window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
    url: url,
    swaggerRequestHeaders: 'application/json;charset=UTF8',
    // ...
```

Comment: I did add swaggerRequestHeaders:'application/json;charset=UTF8'. I am getting the follow as result: 406 : <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.20 - Error report</title><style type="text/css">H1 ........<p><b>description</b> <u>The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.20</h3></body></html> http://localhost:8080/swagger/api-docs

Comment: curl -H Accept:application/json http://localhost:8080/swagger/api-docs also gives a above  
E:\Softwares\curl-7.47.0-win64-mingw\bin>curl -H Accept:application/json http://localhost:8080/swagger/api-docs
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.20 - Error report</title>....... <p><b>description</b>
 <u>The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating respon
ses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" header
s.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.20</h3></body></html>
E:\Softwares\curl-7.47.0-win64-mingw\bin>